# hibernate c3p0 configuration mysql problems

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

im working in a SPRING HIBERNATE MYSQL integration, i have problems in the DB.
These are the errors

```
    ADVERTENCIA: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@41d93e5e is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
mar 11, 2016 11:37:07 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask run
ADVERTENCIA: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@25b7c73 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2214)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
    ... 18 more

mar 11, 2016 11:37:07 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool forceKillAcquires
ADVERTENCIA: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@41d93e5e is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
mar 11, 2016 11:37:09 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask run
ADVERTENCIA: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6529b7c0 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Then my web.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Spring4 MVC Hibernate4 Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my dispatcher-servlet

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
        DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.vacajose" />



    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources
        mapping="/resources/**"
        location="/resources/" />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property
            name="prefix"
            value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property
            name="suffix"
            value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property
            name="driverClass"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property
            name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ranga" />
        <property
            name="user"
            value="usuario" />
        <property
            name="password"
            value="usuario" />
        <property
            name="acquireIncrement"
            value="2" />
        <property
            name="minPoolSize"
            value="20" />
        <property
            name="maxPoolSize"
            value="50" />
        <property
            name="maxIdleTime"
            value="600" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean
        id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property
            name="dataSource"
            ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property
            name="packagesToScan"
            value="org.vacajose.entity"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean
        id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property
            name="sessionFactory"
            ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

i dont know where is the problem

I dont have hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file cause it is in the dispatcher servlet

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.xml, you have to include Spring listener.

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath:spring-file.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

That might be the problem.